# how do I constrain proportions with height related to width

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have evenly spaced included LinearLayouts in a parent LinearLayout which I can do easily using weightSum and layout_weight parameters. I get a good result accept I want the spaced elements to be square. ***How do I force the height to be whatever the width ends up being after evenly spaced?***

Note I've given the 4 included elements a weight of 10 with the spacers a weight of 1 (for a total weight sum of 45).

Thanks very much! This has been bugging me for a while.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlRaces"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="45" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    layout="@layout/races_badge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    layout="@layout/races_badge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    layout="@layout/races_badge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    layout="@layout/races_badge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to do it in XML or you're open for java code ?

Comment: This can't be done in XML i think. layout_weight is calculated in View.onMeasure(); You have to override that and make your custom view.

Comment: @oldergod XML would be preferable but I'm open to Java.

Comment: @wtsang02 if you format that comment into an illustrated answer I will accept it.

Comment: Did it work for you? Because I don't know the exact implementation of the onMeasure(); thats why it was a comment.

Comment: @wtsang02 I played around with some subclasses of LinearLayout with onMeassure overrides but I could't get it to work :(.